# macro in excel tablet

Tags: excel, vba, tablet

ealier i created a vba macro using this code

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Range("A56").Value =  Range("A56").value & " Text"
End Sub
```

it worked great until i opened it in excel mobile
it said it can run vba macro
is there anyway to make it work on a tablet? can i write it differently?
all i want it a fast way to add some premade sentence to a existing field with a value

thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA only runs in Excel for desktop (Windows or Mac). That's not going to change.

You can easily create a worksheet formula that does what your macro does. Instead of ticking a tick box, you can put a character like "y" or "n" into a cell, for example into cell A1. Then you can use a formula like this:

```
=if(A1="y",A56 & " Text","")
```

This formula based approach will work on any Excel platform, i.e. Windows, Mac, web, tablets, and mobiles.

Edit after comment:

If you want to check several cells, then you can nest IF functions or you can use IFS (available only in Office 365).

```
=if(A1="y",A56 & " Text",if(A2="y",A56 & " some other text", if(A3 = "y",A56 & " some third option","other")))
```

using IFS() in Offic 365

```
=IFS(A1="y",A56 & " Text",A2="y",A56 & " some other text",A3 = "y",A56 & " some third option")
```

Comment: thx a lot for ur time and comment i understand what you said but if i want more than 1 choice of text for that line can i do something like that
=IF(E58="y",A56 & " test1","") and IF(E59="y",A56 & " test2","")
is it possible to add multiple choice like that?
thanks again

Comment: you can use nested IF() or you can use the IFS() function if you have Office 365. I added some sample formulas to my answer.,